# Javascript cannot read property of undefined eloquentjavascript

Tags: javascript

I'm going through the eloquentjavascript course, and I had a question about some code.

The problem set is to try to flatten an array using the reduce function. Below is my code:

```
console.log(reduce(arrays, function(flat, current) {
  for (var f = 0; f < (current.length); f++) {
      flat.push(current[f]);
    }}, []))
```

I keep getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (line 17)

Why am I getting this issue? I've set the current to be an empty array (`[]`), so why is it still undefined?

The code for the reduce function is

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show the code for the `reduce()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I just put it in.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know why you wouldn't just say `return flat.concat(current)`.

Comment: @Juhana Actually, the code for the reduce function is irrelevant. The error is perfectly obvious from the code calling it.

Comment: @torazaburo It's not *completely* irrelevant; since it's an array that's being manipulated, the function could just as well return the original array and it would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`function(flat, current)` doesn't return anything, so in this line:

```
current = combine(current, array[i]);
```

`current` will become `undefined` after one iteration of the loop.
You can fix that by adding `return flat;` to the end of your anonymous function:

```
console.log(reduce(arrays, function(flat, current) {
    for (var f = 0; f < (current.length); f++) {
        flat.push(current[f]);
    }
    return flat;
}, []));
```